# SQL query against comma-separated column

Tags: sql

I have a column `categories` in my `company` table. In that `categories` there can be so many categories separated by `,`. Something like `1,2,3,4,5` and I know one of that category `id`.

Let's say `1` for now.

So how I can query `company` table?

Comment: Assuming it's a character field, you can use the [LIKE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) operator:  `where <your column> like '%,1,%'`.

Comment: Can you change the table structure so that it has a row for each category instead?

Comment: @Lamak or better yet, add a new table that has a row for each company/category relationship

Comment: Changing the table structure would be aesthetically nice from some perspectives, but is not functionally necessary unless the data set is "large", where large is dependent on the hardware and usage patterns. Note `LIKE %1%` is INCORRECT. It would match value '12'.

Comment: @zanerock it's not just "aesthetics", this way of storing data makes it very hard to query it (as you can see here), and it isn't even first normal form

Comment: @Lamak The question of "hard" and whether or not 'first normal form' is important are are not specified, and I'm sweeping them under the term 'aesthetics' here. Depending on how the table is being used, what the app does, storing the values in a list may be easier and using first normal form may be entirely irrelevant. The use of a different structure is possibly the right way to go, but possibly not. Indeed, it may not even be possible.

Comment: @zanerock well, of course that if the "app" (assuming there is one) only ever need to return a list of categories for a company (which it clearly isn't the case here, otherwise op wouldn't be asking how to retrieve the companies that have the category 1), then yes, it would be the best way of storing data. For almost every other use case ever, then no, it isn't

Comment: @Andrew you want `WHERE ',' + col + ',' LIKE '%,1,%'` else you'll miss values at the beginning and end of the list.

Comment: @SamIam No, that won't work. Searches for `1` will also match `512` and `1042`.

Comment: @SamIam fake it with a query that doesn't work? Yeah I guess that makes sense.

Comment: @Lamak I understand what you're saying. All I'm saying is that if storing things in a list is a given then it doesn't matter because possible trumps 'better'. Also, if this method is sufficient and easier for the questionner, then what's the problem? You're entirely right to point out the alternative possibility, but there's simply not sufficient information to ascertain which is the possible / better solution.

Comment: @zanerock that's why Lamak *commented* and didn't post his suggestion *as an answer.*

Comment: @AaronBertrand I understand. That's not my issue. He asserted that changing the table structure was better: "better yet, add a new table". My point is that is broad and a value judgement, not a statement of fact. Also, possibly not useful because it's not clear the table structure can be changed.

Comment: @zanerock Did I actually say that, or did I just ask if he could change the table structure?. On the other hand, you are assuming that the way the table is designed is because it's easier for op, when it can perfectly be that s/he doesn't know any other way. If it would be easier, then why is there a question here on how to query his/her table in a way that would be trivial with a table change?

Comment: @Lamak OK... I think this is interesting, but are we hijacking? I'm not an expert on etiquette here. I read "better yet" as saying "it would be better to change the table structure". That's possible not what you meant, but I assert it's a legitimate parse of the statement. "If possible, it might better" would be clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to deal with four cases: the `categories` in question is first in a list, internal to a list, last in a list, and the only categories: `SELECT * FROM company WHERE categories LIKE '1,%' OR categories LIKE '%,1,%' OR categories LIKE '%,1' OR categories='1'`.

Comment: Since you're going to scan anyway, why not simplify? `WHERE ',' + categories + ',' LIKE '%,1,%';`?

Comment: I like it. Whether it's simpler or not depends on the POV. If one understands SQL well, it's little more compact. If not, then it is probably less clear why that version works. I would also think it almost certain the performance is both 'big-O' and practically equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM company 
WHERE (categories like '%,categoryId,%' or categories like 'categoryId,%')
```

The second like clause takes care of your first record which does not have preceding coma

Comment: what about the last one?

Comment: @SamIam Ha ha go crazy and add categories like '%,categoryId'

Comment: This is incorrect. it misses when the categoryId in question is the last and only option in the list.

Comment: `WHERE ',' + Categories + ',' LIKE '%,1,%'`

Comment: @6ton I still can't query for the last.

Comment: You can incorporate one of the suggestions in the comments to this answer

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL has [arrays](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/arrays.html) and [array functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-array.html) which allow you to solve this problem neatly.

Assume the following schema and sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE company
    ("name" varchar(13), "categories" varchar(9));

INSERT INTO company
    ("name", "categories")

VALUES
    ('acme', '1,2,3,4,5'),
    ('abc', '2,3,4'),
    ('xyz', '3,5'),
    ('stackoverflow', '4');
```

Then you can use the ANY operator to find an element in an array like so:

```sql
SELECT
    name

FROM (
    SELECT NAME, string_to_array(categories, ',') AS category_array FROM company
    ) n

WHERE
    '2' = ANY (category_array);
```

Which should return `acme` and `abc`, according to [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b47874/1/0).

Comment: This is also much more power and flexible in that you can query for multiple categories with things like `ARRAY['2','4'] <@ category_array` which checks if `2,4` is contained in any category, returning `acme` and `abc`. See an example at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bd4e2/1